# Solving $(x-2)^2=\sqrt{x}+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve $(x-2)^2=\sqrt{x}+2$
answer is $0.9$ and $4$ 
But no idea with steps

Comment: Does √x+2 mean $\sqrt x+2$ or $\sqrt{x+2}$? In both cases, $0.9$ does not seem to be an answer.

Comment: Rearrange to $(x - 2)^2 - 2 = \sqrt{x}$, then square both sides to produce a polynomial equation. Be sure to discard any erroneous solutions produced by squaring.

Comment: @NECing first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x-2)^2=\sqrt{x}+2$$
$$x^2-4x+2=\sqrt{x}$$
$$x^4+16x^2+4+4x^2-16x-8x^3=x$$
$$x^4-8x^3+20x^2-17x+4=0$$

Now $$x=1,4,\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
But only $$x=4,\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$ satify orginal eqution

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sqrt{x} = t$, then $(t^2-2)^2 = t+2 \to t^4 - 4t^2 + 4 - t - 2 = 0 \to t^4 - 4t^2 -t + 2 = 0 \to t^2(t^2 - 4) - (t-2) = 0 \to (t-2)(t^2(t+2) - 1) = 0 \to (t-2)(t^3 + 2t^2 - 1) = 0 \to (t-2)(t+1)(t^2 + t - 1) = 0$. Can you finish it?